# getting error while sending attachments in mail using RDCOMClient in R studio

Tags: r

I am trying to send email using `RDCOMClient` and here is the code:

```
    library(RDCOMClient)

    emails <- paste("emailid")
    ## init com api
    OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
    ## create an email 
    outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
    ## configure  email parameter 
    outMail[["To"]] = emails
    outMail[["Cc"]] = "emailid"
    outMail[["subject"]] = "Monthly Report for Compliance"
    outMail[["body"]] = paste(" Please find the monthly report  completed for ",Sys.Date(),
                              ".\n\n instrument file is saved at:\n G:\\Data Science\\Monthly Check - Westlake\\Instruments and Issuers Compliance List
                              "
                              )

    outMail[["attachments"]]$Add("G:\\Data Science\\Monthly Check - Westlake\\Instruments and Issuers Compliance List\\Instruments_tracked-.02202018.csv")    
    outMail$Send()
```

... but I get the below error:

> 80020009 ; 
>           No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo ;
>           checkErrorInfo -2147352567

Eventually, the code till body works but the attachment is not available in the final mail throwing the above error.

Comment: Why don't you try `sendmailR` or `mailR`?